# Gulp watch...isn't watching?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I am setting up my gulp.js file and everything is working fine except for gulp.watch. When I run "gulp" in the terminal, gulp runs through each task but doesn't watch for changes. Is there something I should change?

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    del = require('del');

// Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/css/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded', }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});

// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/scripts'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));
});

// Images
gulp.task('images', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/images/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/images'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Images task complete' }));
});


// Default task
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.start('styles', 'scripts', 'images');
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // Watch .scss files
  gulp.watch('src/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);

  // Watch .js files
  gulp.watch('src/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);

  // Watch image files
  gulp.watch('src/images/**/*', ['images']);

  // Create LiveReload server
  livereload.listen();

  // Watch any files in dist/, reload on change
  gulp.watch(['build/**']).on('change', livereload.changed);

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, because the watch task was not called.
Add the watch to your default task

```
// Default task
 gulp.task('default', ['watch'], function() {
   gulp.start('styles', 'scripts', 'images');
 });
```